# How to: Custom CSS File with Webpack? (Nativescript)

Tags: nativescript

For my Nativescript (Angular, iOS) app, I want to have a different css file load if the app is being used on a tablet. I am bundling with webpack.

I found a helpful article here: [link](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/tablet-support-for-nativescript-with-angular). But, I am not able to get the solution from that article to work. I think the issue is I don't know the right code to enter specific to webpack. I probably need something in the webpack.config.js file, but I have not yet figured out what it should be.

Following that article, I have code like this:

app.module.ts:

```
import { DeviceType } from "ui/enums";
import { device } from "platform";
import * as application from "application";
import { setCssFileName } from "application";
const fs = require("file-system");
...
export class AppModule { 

    constructor() {
        if (device.deviceType === DeviceType.Tablet) {
            console.log('now on tablet')           
            let cssFileName = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path, "app.tablet.css");
            fs.File.fromPath(cssFileName).readText().then((result: string) => {
                application.addCss(result);
            });
        }
   }     
}
```

app.tablet.css:

```
.coolTabletStyle {
  font-size: ...
}
```

The console correctly reads "now on tablet", but the tablet css file is not yet used.

What else do I need to add--perhaps in the webpack.config.js file--to get the tablet css file to be used in the case the user is on a tablet?

Comment: May I ask, why don't you try using the [nativescript-platform-css](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-platform-css) plugin and wrap your classes with `.phone` / `.tablet` classes?

Comment: I need the performance ready for production, so I don't want to take any chances. Looks like that plugin has a few key issues that are not resolved:https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-platform-css/issues/25.

Comment: So I would prefer to go the non-plugin route.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where this issue can be reproduced.

Comment: That is difficult given its specific to loading with webpack. The above code works fine without a webpack build. I am not aware of how to specificy the webpack settings in a playground example. In any event, the answer is unlikely specific to my case--I am confident that there needs to be some code added to specific to webpack builds, and I am looking for that code.

Comment: Try to include `app.tablet.css` path in your `CopyWebpackPlugin` configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding: "new CopyWebpackPlugin([ {from: "**/src/app.tablet.css"}, ..." But doesn't work yet. Maybe a different syntax?